# How to send a data array whilst using jquery form plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms, plugins

I'm trying to send an array of data to a php processor page that does some processing tasks such as insertion, etc... but, it seems that the data is not being sent and the php throws this error

**The Error:**

`Notice: Undefined index: reci in C:\Users\YASIN\Desktop\SERVER\htdocs\drawer_mess_page_process.php on line 67
Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in C:\Users\YASIN\Desktop\SERVER\htdocs\drawer_mess_page_process.php on line 67`

**The jquery code that sends the data:**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var reci_arr = [];
        var i = 0;
        $('.recipient_tab').each(function(){
             var a = $(this).attr('data-recipient');
             reci_arr[i++] = $(this).attr('data-recipient');
        });
        var time=new Date().getTime();
        var options = {  
                        url:'processor.php',
                        type:'POST', 
                        resetForm:true,
                        data:{reci:reci_arr,time:time},// the data reci is not being sent other data is being sent
                        beforeSend:function(html){
                                                 },

                        success:function(html) {
                                                 //doing stuffs which works 
                                               },
                      };  

        $('#hide_selector_mess_draw').change(function() 
        {
          $('#add_photo_mess_draw').ajaxForm(options).submit(); 
        });
    });
```

**The php code that processes the data**

```
function clean_arr ($a)
{
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "stark1998" ,"users") or die("Could not connect database");
  return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $a);
}
$reci= array_map('clean_arr', $_POST['reci']);//to_acc
```

Comment: in the js you send two parameter with the keys reci and time, on serverside you ask vor $_POST['recipie'] - typing error, missing code?

Comment: @axel.michel no that was a typo but i think that the .each function is not being called

Answer (score 0):

There was a BUG in older jQuery Form pluign when sending data array. Download latest version (atm 3.51.0-2014.06.20).